# How to make artisan serve work in virtual host?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm on Windows 8 and I'm using WAMP to run my laravel project. I have configured apache and I created a virtual host, to access my app through `http://myapp.dev`.

I would like to know if it's possible to use the built-in php server (to run the laravel aplication through `artisan serve`) to point to my virtualhost instead of `http://localhost:8000`.

I tried to change the app url in `app.php` but it didn't work.

Comment: Point `myapp.dev` to `127.0.0.1` in your hosts file, and do `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80`. In Linux, this requires `sudo` privilege, I'm not sure what Windows will require. You'd want to stop Apache too, as it uses port 80 too.

Comment: Blame me if I'm wrong @ceejayoz but shouldn't that be an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @Peh I'd prefer to let someone who knows the Windows side fill in the missing details.

Comment: Thanks man! It worked. Please post this as the answer so i can accept.

Comment: @PietroCoelho Heh, hooray! Done. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Point `myapp.dev` to `127.0.0.1` in your hosts file, and do `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80`.

In Linux/OSX, this requires sudo privilege, I'm not sure what Windows will require. You'd want to stop Apache too, as it uses port 80 and will cause a conflict if both are trying to run on that port.

Comment: Great answer. Windows does not require any permissions.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need change the `hosts` file (ubuntu => `/etc/hosts`, windows => `$WINDIR/System32/drivers/etc/hosts`).

   `127.0.0.1 myapp.dev`
2. `.env` file also needs changing:

   `APP_URL=tttp://myapp.dev:8000`
3. `$ php artisan serve --host=myapp.dev`